# Spring Security: Unsure of pre-authentication method

Tags: spring-security

My web application uses a pre-authentication method. By the time that the request reaches my application, userPrincipal is correctly set.
I know it's not using Java EE container security, it is using some module configured on the Apache web server.

Therefore, I'm unsure what pre-authetication method to use. Ideally I want something similar to the `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` except that it just reads the userPrincipal from the request instead of the header.

Is there an out of the box mechanism to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just extend and then register [`AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/preauth/AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html), everything is in [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6167):

```
public class RequestPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
    extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

  private static final String USER_PRINCIPAL_KEY = "";

  @Override
  protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getAttribute(USER_PRINCIPAL_KEY);
  }

  @Override
  protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "N/A"; // or whatever you need
  }
}
```

and in security-context.xml:

```
<security:http>
  <!-- Additional http configuration omitted -->
  <security:custom-filter position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" ref="preAuthFilter" />
</security:http>

<bean id="preAuthFilter"
    class="com.example.RequestPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager">
</bean>
```